# How to restart a python script using IDLE Basic

Tags: python

Hey Stackoverflow community,
I'm quite new to coding but recently I have taken an interest in python.
Below I have a sample script that's similiar to what I'm writing.
I can't find anything basic so please keep it simple :D
Also, how would I do this with multiple `if-elif-else`?

```
print('Sample "Console" :D')
console = input('-> ')
if console == 'Restart':
    print('Restarting')
```

If I want to have the code loop from the begining what do I do? Please do a quick rewrite of the code with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use a while loop.

```
while True:
    console = input('->')
    if console != 'Restart' :
        break
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks San! Can I ask what the ! mean?

Comment: '==' means equal and != means 'not equal' .. so it will check for the input string, if it is not equal to 'Restart' it will exit.